# save images in right files

Tags: python, image, directory, save

```
path_school="/content/drive/MyDrive"

test_path=path_school+"//"+"test"
processedex_path=path_school+"//"+"test_ex"

for (path, dir, files) in os.walk(train_path):
    for filename in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1]
        test_folder_list = [f for f in os.listdir(path_school+'//'+'test')] 
        for f in os.listdir(test_path):
          fol=os.path.splitext(f)[-1]
          '''
          os.makedirs(processedex_path+"//"+f)
          '''
        if ext == '.jpg':
            img=Image.open ("%s/%s" % (path, filename)).convert('L')
            img=img.resize((256,256))
            img.save(processedex_path+"//"+f+"//"+"pre"+"_"+filename)
```

in `'test_path'` there are a lot of folders like `'A356_4_50_TS_167'` and in this folder there are images named `'0232-0024.jpg'.`
I want to save images in right place folder '`A356_4_50_TS_167'` in `'processedex_path'` folder.
This code saves every changed images in every folder.
Please help me to save images in right folders.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR9Rz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLmJy.png)

these are my original path and I want to save images in same named folder in 'test_ex'(=processedex_path) folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvLat.png)
but every images from every folders were saved in each folders not 2 images per one folder but 70 images per on folder I want to save 2images per one folder

thank u for answering

Comment: It's not clear to me, what is the right path and what do you mean by "saves every changed images in every folder"

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: you use `os.walk` and two times `os.listdir()` - maybe you have too many `for`-loops.  As for me you should use only one `os.lisdir` with `'test_path'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't run your code but I think you have too many `for`-loops

I would do

```
import os
from PIL import Image

path_school = "/content/drive/MyDrive"

# source & destination folder
test_path        = os.path.join(path_school, "test")
processedex_path = os.path.join(path_school, "test_ex")

os.makedirs(processedex_path, exist_ok=True)

for subfolder in os.listdir(test_path):
    
    # source & destination subfolder
    src_subfolder = os.path.join(test_path, subfolder)
    dst_subfolder = os.path.join(processedex_path, subfolder)

    if os.path.isdir(src_subfolder):  # check if it is really subfolder

        os.makedirs(dst_subfolder, exist_ok=True)
                    
        for filename in os.listdir(src_subfolder):
            if filename.lower().endswith( ('.jpg', '.png', 'webp') ):
                # source & destination file
                src_file = os.path.join(src_subfolder, filename)
                dst_file = os.path.join(dst_subfolder, "pre_"+filename)
                    
                img = Image.open(src_file).convert('L')
                img = img.resize((256, 256))
                img.save(dst_file)

                print('converted:', filename)
                print('src:', src_file)
                print('dst:', dst_file)
```